# can we insert date into varchar2 in oracle without converting by to_char?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

can we insert date into varchar2  in oracle without converting by to_char?

Answer (score 1):

Oracle will convert the date into a string using what localization settings are in place during the insert. This is true not only of Oracle but of any database. For a date, that might commonly be in the format "DD-MON-YY".

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=520b58e117ec636bbb244583023047ea) is an example of inserting a date into a `varchar2` column.

That said, you *should not* do this. You should be storing date/time values in the database using the correct data type -- and that would be either `date` or `timestamp`. If you want to insert a constant, then use the `date` or `timestamp` qualifier with the appropriate value following it.

Comment: woww....i was looking for this answer for hours on google and you just made it clear in one minute. just another question- what do mean by localization settings. what they should be or where can i check them?

Comment: @Dharmendra . . . Those really are not important.  They just specify what the default format would be for a month -- for instance, would the month names be in English or in another language?  It is better not to rely on those defaults, which is why you should store the value as a `date` or `timestamp`.

Comment: Understood sir. thanks.   actually my insert is trying to insert date into this varchar2 column and failing but when i used to_char at that column it started working. do you think i did it correct way?

Comment: In Oracle at least, the default NLS_DATE_FORMAT that comes pre-installed with the database is DD-MON-RR (rather than YY).

Comment: @Dharmendra - you said "when i used to_char at that column it started working. do you think i did it correct way?".  Technically, yes. But I would re-emphasize what Gordon said - "you should not do this. You should be storing date/time values in the database using the correct data type".  For more about this, see https://edstevensdba.wordpress.com/2011/04/07/nls_date_format/

Comment: @EdStevens yes you are right and i will keep your recommendations from next time. but this thing is already in production so i tried using to_char. but anyways thank you so much for your help i have raised it back to the developers.